# Server-sent-events (SSE) not working if done only with nginx static server

Tags: javascript, nginx, server-sent-events

I've been trying for an entire day to make SSE work using only nginx (without proxy_pass), and later with proxy_pass just for the sake of trying stuff, but when connecting to the endpoint using JavaScript's EventSource, it keeps disconnecting after receiving the first event, and reconnecting again. This defeats the point of SSE, since it feels more like polling. My goal is to have SSE reconnect when we deploy a new nginx static server to production, so that I can send an event message with the current commit hash (added to the nginx config during docker build or docker run), here's the code that's almost working, as you'll see I tried both via a proxy_pass and without it, both endpoints suffer from the same "bug":

```
# load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;
# user       www www;  ## Default: nobody
worker_processes  1;
# error_log  logs/error.log;
# pid        logs/nginx.pid;
# worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    # send_timeout 1800;
    # keepalive_timeout 10m;
    # client_max_body_size 128M;
    # proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    # proxy_buffering off;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;
        # index index.html;
        # root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location = /sse {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_pass http://proxy;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_request_buffering off;
            proxy_cache off;

            # proxy_connect_timeout 159s;
            # proxy_send_timeout   600;
            # proxy_read_timeout   600;
            # proxy_buffer_size    64k;
            # proxy_buffers     16 32k;
            # proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
            # proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
            fastcgi_keep_conn on;

            # add_header Connection "keep-alive";
            # add_header X-Accel-Buffering "no";
            # chunked_transfer_encoding on;
            # more_clear_headers "Content-Length";
            # default_type text/event-stream;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8081;
        server_name localhost;

        location = /sse {
            # add_header Connection "keep-alive";
            # expires off;
            # default_type text/event-stream;
            default_type "";
            add_header Content-Type "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8";
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            push_stream_eventsource_support on;
            
            add_header X-Accel-Buffering "no";
            # chunked_transfer_encoding off;
            # keepalive_timeout 100s;
            return 200 "event: ping\ndata: {\"time\": \"foo\"}\n\n";
        }
    }

    upstream proxy {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const source = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/sse');

  source.addEventListener(
    'open',
    function (e) {
      console.log('Connection was opened.', e.readyState);
    },
    false
  );

  source.addEventListener(
    'error',
    function (e) {
      console.log(e.readyState, e);
      if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
        // Connection was closed.
      }
    },
    false
  );

  source.addEventListener('ping', function (event) {
    console.log('ping', event);
  });
});
```

What I see is "Connection was opened." followed by a successful "ping" message being sent, and 3 seconds later the same and the same. The connection is being "closed" from nginx's side. I have tried the same with a tiny express.js server and this doesn't happen, it would work as expected. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Nginx will closing connection after 3 sec, while its not receiving any data from client side. This because SSE connections are expected one-way. Its server sending data to client.

To fixing, you need to create a heartbeat message from client to server back every few seconds. This will keep the connection alive and prevent Nginx from closing it.

```js
const source = new EventSource('http://example:8080/sse');

source.addEventListener(
  'open',
  function (event) {
    console.log('Connection was opened.', event.readyState);

    //  This is heartbeat message every 3 sec.
    setInterval(() => {
      source.send('ping');
    }, 3000);
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it documented anywhere that nginx will close the connection after n (3) seconds? Can this be changed effectively to allow for like 60 minutes?

Comment: NGINX will close inactive connection after 3 seconds not explicitly documented, but its a known limitation of it software. This limitation is due to the way that NGINX manages its worker processes.